# PCAP get body of HTTP POST requests

Tags: http, post, tcpdump

I have a PCAP file with dump of network traffic to web server/web application. I would like to get this PCAP file and somehow extract from it only BODY of HTTP requests and only for POST method on page (preferably in one file, one request per line)

Comment: Did you try Wireshark or tshark?

Comment: I do try to import file in wireshark, but I don't know how to export exactly body of HTTP POST (I implemented filtering for POST data successfuly). As far as I have read, there is no easy way to do this using tshark

Comment: This is another good job for Python and Scapy.

Answer (score 0):

If your post bodies are small one liners themselves - the following should work:

```
$ tcpdump -A -r mycap.pcap \                                  # display ascii
| awk '/POST \/page.html/{f=1;next} /IP6.*options/{f=0} f' \  # filter stuff related to the page
| perl -npe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/([^\n]+\n)+\n([^\n]+)/\2/smg' # headers and body are separated by \n\n
```